# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I got an assignment in my Python 1 class consisting of this:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

You are a score keeper for 20 ice hockey players. Implement the code to keep track of their scores using a list. Program accepts integers as input and it is called YI_ScoreKeeper.py. Simulate a game by entering a good number of scores.

Here are two pics. she gave(I don't have enough rep. to post them as images)

[image: https://e.edim.co/29892634/screen_shot_2015_01_09_at_9_30_52_am_t.png?Expires=1422066625&Signature=Ql0P778epTnFNUD~4AiZtwr5Gip~JTgohs8ShfVD5Yzvghot0hTATBAbktvD6whm~WG8a9gSJ98fihD81NLyPf7E615hMKaYOBIxLJZp4M1l1EBAYHGZZeDY6xblYlb-PelzwDo8USbcCuq8OAIioaiMrWeQ2WV5X4YUmqwZHbgqPGYvXP~nhupH7qoTdLUagdleySQ8S8BhG6at0YeHwd5pgwMh-Lq3hJ97lfmsrhYeWhG~yr6t3WpzZmgWPVg1WRo1lbPNC5Y91952iDub-20aZuK2sDngcTSf7BnBfn6laIeN~Ib3uhX~KJe9tcWs0EY~CwiDl~-rXIB73f5uIQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIJNVNRBLLSTGN23Q]

[image: https://e.edim.co/29892634/screen_shot_2015_01_09_at_9_31_36_am_t.png?Expires=1422066625&Signature=Bgf-JQNNMnkHT3Taocc-rxqo4F2BJLAGdcl-qZpJHcFWBov0rvTvktQxBklJGIXk~Y7or1KFJQIvLWw2Fsr002XtB0N7qqQZLl3FRc8nmEvE~sIt0atsZmj4V8Fq9OSkO6UjMgHroIBtl2NlhRJ2DoSWoDyoMT13ODN7AUuyClwwFB5PlJW2TtUeF5mOUyN0eOXzYV-jk4oEyptnK2RYwbSo-b-mY677mkK66iBiPCkcSQPciJs3VOxfopNhshWYb01CbYcDI0inJ2FqD3t8WLQfzmzY8HRy8A2aFgrJIM1OsAh9xKcb49zRSsfUP9W0lxmh007wxC8dLbu06Y1XVw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIJNVNRBLLSTGN23Q]

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So far, my code is this:

```
def scorekeeper():
    Scorekeeper = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    return Scorekeeper

def addscore(Scorekeeper):
    Addscore = int(input("what player scored a goal?"))
    Addscore = Addscore - 1 
    (Scorekeeper[Addscore]) = ((Scorekeeper[Addscore]) + 1) 
    return Scorekeeper
def histogram(Scorekeeper):
    print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
    print("%s %10s %10s" %("Element", "Ranking", "Histogram"))
    for i in range(len(Scorekeeper)):
        print("%7d%5d %-s" % (i +1, Scorekeeper[i], "*" * Scorekeeper[i])) 
def main():
    Scorekeeper = scorekeeper()
    endgame = 'n'
    while endgame == 'n':
        Addscore = addscore(scorekeeper)
        endgame = input("Has the game ended? y/n")

    histogram(scorekeeper)

main()
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I keep on getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/scorekeeper.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python34/scorekeeper.py", line 22, in main
    Addscore = addscore(scorekeeper)
  File "C:/Python34/scorekeeper.py", line 11, in addscore
    (Scorekeeper[Addscore]) = ((Scorekeeper[Addscore]) + 1)
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Help? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You made a small mistake here:

```
def main():
    Scorekeeper = scorekeeper()
    endgame = 'n'
    while endgame == 'n':
        addscore(Scorekeeper) # This was set to scorekeeper
        endgame = input("Has the game ended? y/n")

    histogram(Scorekeeper) # Here too
```

Rather than calling the `addscore` function with the `Scorekeeper` list you'd already returned from `scorekeeper()`, you were just sending in the function `scorekeeper`.

This is why you were getting the error message; you were expecting to modify the `ScoreKeeper` list with the index syntax you used, but instead you had a function object. Hope this clears it up.

#### Edit:

As pointed out by *@KevinJ.Chase*:

The `Addscore` in `Addscore = addscore(scorekeeper)` didn't change anything. In Python, *references to objects* are passed in as function parameters. What this means is that the passed parameter (inside the function) is a new identifier binded to the same object. While the logic involved here is not that terribly important to understand when passing immutable objects like an `Int`, a `Str` (etc.), passing a `list` means the new identifier inside the function references the same mutable data (the `list`). In this case, that mutable data was modified inside the function call; so returning it was indeed unnecessary.

Comment: Also, the capital-A `Addscore` variable is never used, so the small-a `addscore` function's return value is thrown away every time.  The code only works because the return value of `addscore` is _completely useless_:  `addscore` mutates the list it's given, so returning that mutated list gives the caller a list it _already has_ (it's how the caller passed the list to `addscore` in the first place).  Storing that return value then creates the illusion that `Scorekeeper` and `Addscore` are two different lists, when they are actually just _one_ list.  `addscore` should return nothing.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Guilty as charged. I noticed it, but I tried keeping the answer as relevant to the problem at hand. I'll clean it up, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the function to access the list:

```
(Scorekeeper()[Addscore]) = ((Scorekeeper()[Addscore]) + 1)
```

You also need to call the function in your loop:

```
 for i in range(len(Scorekeeper())):
        print("%7d%5d %-s" % (i +1, Scorekeeper()[i], "*" * Scorekeeper()[i]))
```

But really you should just declare a list outside of the functions and just access the list directly and forget about using the functions:

`scorekeeper = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

You can change the histogram function yourself but this is an idea of how to write simpler more straight forward code:

```
def add_score():
    score = int(input("what player scored a goal?"))
    return score


def main():
    endgame = 'n'
    score_keeper = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    while endgame == 'n':
        scorer = add_score()
        score_keeper[scorer] += 1
        endgame = input("Has the game ended? y/n")
```

When taking input and especially casting you should use a [try/except](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) to validate so I would add a second while loop in `add_score` with a try except.

Comment: @Eithos, wrong again I am afraid. look at what is passed in to the functions

Comment: That's just the parameter. In `main()`, you can clearly see the function `scorekeeper` returns a list, which is what he meant to pass off to all the other functions. Edit: Technically, you're right. But, I mean... it's obvious that this was a typo on his part isn't it?

Comment: @Eithos, it is late, I am not going to argue, you are incorrect . If you actually ran the code with my changes you would see that it works. You answer does not even address the many errors

Comment: Don't take offense, please. I'm sorry if I come across as purposely annoying--it's not my intention. I just ran the fixes you made to his code: The problem is each time you call that function again, you're geting a new list, so you aren't keeping score. Your second example works fine (with the proposed alterations), but I think you meant for this `scorekeeper[scorer]` to be this `score_keeper[scorer]`

Comment: Yes thanks, a typo, not offended just too tired to argue,  yes the code makes no sense but I was just showing why it happened and how to fix it,  it was easier to give an example of how to simplify the code than try to point out and fix all the logic issues with the OP's code.

Comment: @Padraic, @Eithos is correct...  Your first solution --- calling `scorekeeper` over and over --- keeps throwing out the user's input and resetting the scores to zero.  Stephen's mistake wasn't failing to call the function passed to `addscore` and `histogram`, but passing them a function in the first place.  They are supposed to operate on a list, not a function.  (For the record, before I even read his code, I said to myself "He forgot the ()s at the end of a function name somewhere."  It's such a common mistake that it was really hard to see that the real error was completely different.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase, it is not a solution to fix the code it is the answer to why the code was throwing an error.  The second part of the answer is how to actually have working code